# SharePoint 2010- Send reminders from Task assigned

Tags: 2010, alert, task-list

I am working on a project and its on SharePoint. I have to send reminders to Team Members whom I have assigned a task. But the workflows in SharePoint are restricted. We don't have the designer access?

Can anyone let me know is there any other way to send reminders to Team Members for the task assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Send the reminder email programmatically.

Check this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32753/Send-scheduled-Reminder-Alerts-by-email-in-SharePo